# Python: VMware Object data

Tags: python, object, properties, vmware, suds

How does one get all the property values from an object. For example a method returned me an object, but when I print it out there's only type and value displayed. For example I've got an ManagedObjectReference of Task named obj. If I write print obj.info an error occurs:

AttributeError: returnval instance has no attribute 'info'

Comment: Add some context around your question.  What API/SDK is being used?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PropertyCollector's RetrieveProperties, CheckForUupdates etc then in PropertyFilterSpec set PropertySpec.all=True. This will fetch all properties of the MOR. But this will be a huge performance hit. Instead I would suggest list out the properties you need in the PropertySpec.pathSet.